# use multiple cpp files in nodejs by n-api

Tags: c++, node.js

I am new to n-api module. On combination two cpp files, getting the following error on execution of node-gyp configure build.

```
b.obj : error LNK2005: _register_a_ already defined in a.obj [e:\democppmore\build\a.vcxproj]
b.obj : error LNK2005: "struct napi_value__ * __cdecl Init(struct napi_env__ *,struct napi_value__ *
)" (?Init@@YAPEAUnapi_value__@@PEAUnapi_env__@@PEAU1@@Z) already defined in a.obj [e:\democppmore\bu
ild\a.vcxproj]
```

I suspect this is due to napi_value Init() present in 2 different cpp codes. If so, how can we overcome it & how our gyp & js files need to be written?

I have the following code:

```js
a.cc
-------
#include <node_api.h>
#include <assert.h>

napi_value Method(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
//some code
}

#define DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD(name, func)                          \
  { name, 0, func, 0, 0, 0, napi_default, 0 }

napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
  napi_status status;
  napi_property_descriptor desc = DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("hello", Method);
  status = napi_define_properties(env, exports, 1, &desc);
  assert(status == napi_ok);
  return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

binding.gyp
--------------
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "module",
      "sources": [ 
        "./src/a.cc",
        "./src/b.cc" ]
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <node_api.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
napi_value Add(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
//some code here
}

#define DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD(name, func)                          \
  { name, 0, func, 0, 0, 0, napi_default, 0 }

napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
  napi_status status;
  napi_property_descriptor addDescriptor = DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("add", Add);
  status = napi_define_properties(env, exports, 1, &addDescriptor);
  assert(status == napi_ok);
  return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

Comment: The primary problem here is duplicated `NAPI_MODULE` blocks. You should leave only one and have only one Init function that should perform all the initialization.

Comment: @VTT I am new to this module and dont know how to do this. Any ref plz?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party. But since this is the only post that relates to the issue that I was struggling with. Luckily, I found the example (you can find other examples as well) from the official `nodejs`, so I want to share it here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/master/6_object_wrap

Editted: I included the way I achieved this problem:

In the `Init` method, I declared the `descriptor` as an array. `napi_define_properties` lets you pass in an array of methods.

Code:

```cpp
// addon.cc
#include <node_api.h>

static napi_value Add()
{
    // Code
}

static napi_value Subtract()
{
    // Code
}

#define DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD(name, func) { name, 0, func, 0, 0, 0, napi_default, 0 }

static napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports)
{
    napi_status status;

    // Declare descriptor as an array
    napi_property_descriptor desc[] = { 
        DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("subtract", Subtract),
        DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("add", Add)
    };
    // Remeber to change the length of the descriptor as well
    status = napi_define_properties(env, exports, sizeof(desc) / sizeof(*desc), desc);
    assert(status == napi_ok);
    return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I just added my solution that I found for my issue.